# Text Based Basic Formula Calculator Function/Class

Tags: c#, math, operators, formula

Looking for something like

```html
int Result; 
DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
var v = dt2.Compute("3+2-34*12", "");
Result=Convert.ToInt32(v);
```

the code above, which solves the text base formula. Unfortunately, the code above only works for some basic operators (+,-,/,*). Need a little more complex one (like squareroot, ^ at least).

Could you help me to find something tosolve for a little more complex equations?

Comment: http://mathparser.org/ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Roslyn [scripting API](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Scripting-API-Samples) for that. Add *Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting* package and evaluate C# code like this:

```
static async Task<double> EvaluateFormulaAsync(string formula)
{
    return await CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync<double>(formula,
        ScriptOptions.Default.WithImports("System.Math"));
}
```

Usage:

```
var result = EvaluateFormulaAsync("Sqrt(2) + 2 * 15").Result; // 31.4142135623731
```

Note: Scripting API requires .NET Framework 4.6+ or .NET Core 1.1