# Text Based Basic Formula Calculator Function/Class v2

Tags: c#, math, operators

This is a follow up question to [Text Based Basic Formula Calculator Function/Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43552723/text-based-basic-formula-calculator-function-class)

I have tried using a simply math formula which was 2^3 as you seen below by using *Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting*:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting;
using org.mariuszgromada.math;
using org.mariuszgromada.math.mxparser;


namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task<double> EvaluateFormulaAsync(string formula)
        {
            return await CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync<double>(formula, ScriptOptions.Default.WithImports("System.Math"));
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var result = EvaluateFormulaAsync("2 ^ 8").Result;
            Console.WriteLine(result);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

But I got **10** as a result instead of **256**. Why could this happen?

Seconly, tried MXParser but I did everything explained in their web site. But I did not make it work with the code below and got exception at

I do not know why these do not work at all. Please help me to find something better or help me to make these work please.

> String result = mXparser.numberToAsciiString(eh.calculate());

Exception: *System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException*

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting;
using org.mariuszgromada.math;
using org.mariuszgromada.math.mxparser;


namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Expression eh = new Expression("2^8");
            String result = mXparser.numberToAsciiString(eh.calculate());
            Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt32(result));

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please remove the images and paste the code/exceptions as text

Comment: @SirRufo done that.

Comment: mXparser.numberToAsciiString() is a method only to show "Helo World" based on math formula ;-) It converts bytes into text. It cannot be used to evaluate expressions. For that purpose follow the mXparser tutorial http://mathparser.org/mxparser-tutorial/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I got 10 as a result. Why could this happen?

The `CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync` method, as it name suggests, evaluates **C# expressions**. So:

```
var result = EvaluateFormulaAsync("2 ^ 8").Result;
```

is the same as:

```
var result = 2 ^ 8;
```

What other result did you expect from the bitwise xor operator? In C# there's no power operator. You could use the `Math.Pow` method instead:

```
var result = EvaluateFormulaAsync("System.Math.Pow(2, 8)").Result;
```

If you want to evaluate mathematical expressions then you may checkout the [mXparser](http://mathparser.org/mxparser-hello-world/mxparser-hello-world-c/) library:

```
var ex = new Expression("2 ^ 8");
double result = ex.calculate();
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: Thanks god, you are the best :)

Answer (score 0):

In C# the `^` operator is bitwise xor, and not exponent.

The xor is 1 when exactly one of the operands is 1. So your example in binary would be:

```
    1000 = 8
    0010 = 2
xor ----
    1010 = 10
```